# Spring Boot Admin Eureka Authentication

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-admin

I am using Eureka discovery, Spring Boot Admin (1.5.4) and several services. Each service has enabled basic auth to actuator endpoints:

```
security.user.name=admin
security.user.password=admin
management.security.enabled=true
```

SBA fetches info about services from eureka and because of secured endpoints I have configured eureka's metadata map like this:

```
eureka.instance.metadata-map.user.name=${security.user.name}
eureka.instance.metadata-map.user.password=${security.user.password}
```

but still getting 401 Unauthorized:

```
o.s.b.a.e.m.MvcEndpointSecurityInterceptor - Full authentication is required to access actuator endpoints. Consider adding Spring Security or set 'management.security.enabled' to false.
```

What am I missing? If I turn `management.security.enabled` off it works.

Comment: Did you try to access actuator's endpoint with `curl` or web browser ? what happened ?

Comment: Have you added spring security dependency in the pom.xml

Comment: security dependency solved the issue

Comment: Please I'm having this problem too and it's been driving me crazy for hours. Which dependency did you add exactly? Where? I guess to the Spring Boot Admin pom isn't it?. Thanks in advance

Comment: Solved, the problem in my case was I had put the "eureka.instance.metadata-map.user.name" part on the Spring Boot Admin configuration instead of on the micro-service side. If the SBA is the one accessing Eureka to locate the actuators why do you have to configure each micro?. I think the documentation (http://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/current/#_securing_client_actuator_endpoints) is not very clear about this point.

Comment: In, my case better to have two separate services for Eureka and for SBA, according to https://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/current/#faqs